# Proyecto Spring + Maven despliega sin cargar estáticos lanzando Excepción

Tags: java, spring

Tengo un proyecto web en desarrollado en Spring y Maven, que depende de otros dos proyectos con el mismo framework (constituyen el backend de la aplicación). La aplicación está ejecutándose en un servidor WebSphere Liberty. A raíz de un despliegue con Jenkins y subida de versión en los ficheros pom.xml ha dejado de cargar los ficheros estáticos (css & js) y me arroja los siguientes errores en el log del servidor:

```
    java.lang.Throwable: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4900)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.getRequestPath(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.matches(DefaultSecurityFilterChain.java:42)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.getFilters(FilterChainProxy.java:224)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:196)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at [internal classes]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    ... 1 more
```

La aplicación se despliega y abre el sitio web, pero sin cargar los estáticos. La configuración del fichero web.xml es =>

```
....
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>asdf-web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                WEB-INF/spring/asdf-web-applicationContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>asdf-web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/asdf/error/resourceNotFound</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/asdf/error/accesDenied</location>
    </error-page>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/asdf/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Esta es la configuración de Spring Security:

```
<http pattern="/static/css/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/static/js/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/static/img/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/static/fonts/**" security="none"/>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir la configuración de spring security que tienes en el proyecto?

Comment: editado, he añadido la configuración para los estáticos en spring security

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente el error se debía a un problema en la versión de los proyectos jar de los que depende. en el fichero pom.xml